# How to Rename Theme Folder in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to change the `Magento 2.1.0` theme folder name to my **companyname**. But I cannot find any help online.

Please help.

Comment: Which theme folder you are trying to change ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution to change theme name:
1) Change folder name:

> app/design/frontend/{your-vendor}/{folder-theme}/

2) Change path name in registration.php file:

> app/design/frontend/{your-vendor}/{folder-theme}/registration.php

```
<?php    
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/{your-vendor}/{folder-theme}',
    __DIR__
);
```

3) Change path name in theme.xml file:

> app/design/frontend/{your-vendor}/{folder-theme}/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>{theme-name}</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

NOTE: After changing you have to run this conmand:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: i tried same as you mention. But I got these errors.
There has been an error processing your request

Item (Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data) with the same ID "0" already exists.

Comment: give me your file content: app/design/frontend/{your-vendor}/{folder-theme}/registration.php

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/default/zaid',
    __DIR__
);

Comment: Please change 'default' to another name

Comment: Thanks alot. Your method worked. Real issue is regarding to my DB->database->theme table was not auto incrementing my values, and also I changed composer.json file.

Answer (score 1):

First,you need to check the magento blog http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

**There are few step,you need to do for this changes:**

Change folder name from

```
app/design/frontend/<ThemeVendorname>/<YourCurrentTHeme>
```

**to**

```
app/design/frontend/[YorComapanyname]/[YourThemeName]
```

**As you have changing folder name so, you need to change some files**

**registration.php  -> app/design/frontend/[YorComapanyname]/[YourThemeName]**

*Change:*

```
frontend/<ThemeVendorname>/<YourCurrentTHeme>
```

to

```
 frontend/[YorComapanyname]/[YourThemeName]
```

Also, at `composer.json` file ,you can change theme name "name": `"magento/[Current_theme_value]"` to You wish

1. Delete old theme registration from db at theme table.Please take  db
   back before do that
2. Then You need flus magento cache
3. apply theme from [admin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)
4. Then **you should deploy  static content**

Comment: what to do with theme registration from DB. Should I delete all the data from theme table !

Comment: Your answer is also a correct one. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

For the renaming theme, you have to create your own then and copy paste default theme content in your theme.

**1. Create Theme Directory**

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themename>
```

**2. Declare your theme**

app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/composer.json

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
  <title>m2-theme</title>
  <parent>Magento/Luma</parent><!--here you can add your parent theme-->
  <media>
     <preview_image>media/m2-theme-image.jpg</preview_image> <!-- add image path {optional} -->
  </media>
</theme>
```

**3. Make Your Theme a Composer package**

app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/composer.json

```
{
 "name": "<vendor>/<themename>", //Change with your vendor and theme
 "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
   "<vendor>/<themename>": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-theme",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

**4.Add registration.php to register your theme**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
 'frontend/<vendor>/<themename>',
  __DIR__
);
```

Now go to **Stores > Configuration > Design**  in your admin section.
and select your theme

**NOTE**: don't forget to **recompile** and **deploy**

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your theme

app/design/frontend/Magento/theme

and here you see **theme.xml** file.

Just change Title Name as you want as a theme name and it's displayed in backend admin theme name.

Answer (score -3):

Follow above step

1. Give Write recursive permission to Design folder

Comment: Is that really Answer to my question! @mrunmay-deswandikar