# How to rename magento 2 theme name

Tags: magento2, php, theme

I am trying to change the Magento 2.1.0 theme folder name to my company name.I cannot found right solution.

Please help.

Comment: Take a look at:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152142/how-to-rename-theme-folder-in-magento2

Comment: @MakisPapadopoulos yeah tried that method but after deploying its not showing in backed  even cleared cache. help me !!

Comment: Cannot read contents from file "C:/wamp64/www/market/" Warning!file_get_contents(C:/wamp64/www/market/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory Getting this Warning

Comment: I am getting error while following this step ..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152142/how-to-rename-theme-folder-in-magento2 .